# Any decent way of printing out floats and doubles with commas?

Tags: c

I'm working on a program that regards with currency. Ive been finding a solution to display money values decently like this:

```
9,999.99 USD
```

Remember when assigning a certain variable with a value (money), you musn't insert commas.

I.e.:

```
double money=9999.99;
```

And when accessing it;

```
printf("%.2l USD",money);
```

Which will output:

```
9999.99 USD
```

This is not what I want, especially on bigger amounts exceeding the hundredth, thousandth, millionth, or even billionth place value.

Now I can't find any solution than printing out the desired output directly on the printf.

```
printf("9,999.99");
```

Which is undesirable with many variables.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Sure. First piece of advice: don't use all-caps in the title. It's already bold and of a larger size so it's emphasized enough.

Comment: As a general hint, using floating point for things like money is not very good, as the compounded rounding errors in calculations may create unexpected values. Instead store cents in an integer, and divide by 100 when needed.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look and [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) manual page taking note of the following bit:

*"For some numeric conversions a radix character ("decimal point") or thousands' grouping character is used. The actual character used depends on the LC_NUMERIC part of the locale. The POSIX locale uses '.' as radix character, and does not have a grouping character. Thus,
    printf("%'.2f", 1234567.89);
results in "1234567.89" in the POSIX locale, in "1234567,89" in the nl_NL locale, and in "1.234.567,89" in the da_DK locale."*

This can be changed by the function [setlocale](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setlocale)

Comment: It should be emphasized that this is part of the POSIX standard and not the C standard, so it is not necessarily available everywhere (e.g., Windows).

Comment: Still, it's not part of the C standard, not even C11, so it's not going to be present on a system just because that system has C.

Comment: Point taken - but there is a rendition for windows as shown by the link.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function, [strfmon](http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V40G_HTML/MAN/MAN3/0618____.HTM) which might be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use floating-point types to represent money because normally floating-point types are binary and as such cannot represent all decimal fractions (cents) exactly, further these types are prone to rounding errors. Use integers instead and count cents instead of dollars.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

unsigned long long ConstructMoney(unsigned long long dollars, unsigned cents)
{
  return dollars * 100 + cents;
}

void PrintWithCommas(unsigned long long n)
{
  char s[sizeof n * CHAR_BIT + 1];
  char *p = s + sizeof s;
  unsigned count = 0;
  *--p = '\0';
  do
  {
    *--p = '0' + n % 10;
    n /= 10;
    if (++count == 3 && n)
    {
      *--p = ',';
      count = 0;
    }
  } while (n);
  printf("%s", p);
}

void PrintMoney(unsigned long long n)
{
  PrintWithCommas(n / 100);
  putchar('.');
  n %= 100;
  putchar('0' + n / 10);
  putchar('0' + n % 10);
}

int main(void)
{
  PrintMoney(ConstructMoney(0, 0)); puts("");
  PrintMoney(ConstructMoney(0, 1)); puts("");
  PrintMoney(ConstructMoney(1, 0)); puts("");
  PrintMoney(ConstructMoney(1, 23)); puts("");
  PrintMoney(ConstructMoney(12, 34)); puts("");
  PrintMoney(ConstructMoney(123, 45)); puts("");
  PrintMoney(ConstructMoney(1234, 56)); puts("");
  PrintMoney(ConstructMoney(12345, 67)); puts("");
  PrintMoney(ConstructMoney(123456, 78)); puts("");
  PrintMoney(ConstructMoney(1234567, 89)); puts("");
  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/eK0dwg)):

```
0.00
0.01
1.00
1.23
12.34
123.45
1,234.56
12,345.67
123,456.78
1,234,567.89
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the standard library, there's no way to do this -- you have to write some code that does it by hand.

I would recommend multiplying the value by 100, casting to integer, and printing the digits with separators as needed -- it's much easier to handle individual digits on an integer.

The following code, for instance, will fill a `char *` buffer with the string representation of the value you have:

```
void formatString (double number, char * buffer) {
  if (number < 0) {
    *buffer = '-';
    formatString(number, buffer + 1);
    return;
  }
  unsigned long long num = (unsigned long long) (number * 100);
  unsigned long long x; // temporary storage for counting the digits
  unsigned char digits;
  for (x = num / 1000, digits = 1; x; digits ++, x /= 10);
    // counts the digits, also ensures that there's at least one digit
  unsigned char pos; // digit position
  for (pos = 1, x = 100; pos < digits; pos ++, x *= 10);
    // reuses x as a value for extracting the digit in the needed position;
  char * current = buffer;
  for (pos = digits; pos; pos --) {
    *(current ++) = 48 + (num / x);
      // remember 48 + digit gives the ASCII for the digit
    if (((pos % 3) == 1) && (pos > 1)) *(current ++) = ',';
    num %= x;
    x /= 10;
  }
  *(current ++) = '.';
  *(current ++) = 48 + num / 10;
  *(current ++) = 48 + num % 10;
  *current = 0;
}
```

Comment: "If you're using the standard library, there's no way to do this" - Ed Heal just did this. Also, better use `'A'` instead of 48.

Comment: @H2CO3: Ed Heal's answer uses POSIX features which are not part of the C standard library.

Comment: @DietrichEpp They're part of the POSIX C standard library.

Comment: @H2CO3: I feel like I'm banging my head against a wall here.  Not all C implementations are also POSIX implementations.  This feature is not part of the C89, C99, or C11 standards.  Is that explicit enough?

Comment: @DietrichEpp Sure. I see you care about non-POSIX systems. Too bad.

Comment: @H2CO3: No need to belittle me.  Lots of embedded and real-time systems make no attempt at POSIX compliance, this is normal.

Comment: @DietrichEpp "No need to belittle me" - just what I wanted to say.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I didn't want to offend either. Peace.